# Laravel check if url is and do nothing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to do not delete if the {id} is #1.

**Code:**

```
if (request()->is('/admin/servers/admin/delete/1')) {
    return Redirect::to("/admin/servers/admins");
}
```

**All function:**

```
public function admins_delete($id)

    {
        if (request()->is('/admin/servers/admin/delete/1')) {
            return Redirect::to("/admin/servers/admins");
        }
        DB::table('server_admins')->where('id',$id)->delete();
        return Redirect::to("/admin/servers/admins");
    }

}
```

But does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you put this code? What is not working? Does it error? Does it remove the admin?

Comment: Thanks for anser. I put in my controller. Not working, becouse still can delete the {id} 1.

Comment: If you `dd()` something in the if-statement, does it actually halt? If no, your if-statement is incorrect. If yes, there is something really weird going on.

Comment: why don't you do directly an id check ? like : `if ($id === 1) {
            return Redirect::to("/admin/servers/admins");
        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this way :

```
 public function admins_delete($id)

        {
            if ($id==1) {
                return Redirect::to("/admin/servers/admins");
            }else{
               DB::table('server_admins')->where('id',$id)->delete();
               return Redirect::to("/admin/servers/admins");
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `->is` function will append the slash to your url for you, so your if case should be like this:

```
if (request()->is('admin/servers/admin/delete/1')) {
    ...
}
```